# Using Int, combined with a String to print existing String

Tags: ios, swift

newbie programmer here, can't figure out why it does it...

```
let a1 = "This is some text"
let x : Int = 1

var stringValue = "a\(x)"

print(stringValue)
```

I want it to print `"This is some text"`, but it only ever prints `a1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing 'This is some text' in a1 string, save it in a dictionary so you can create the key (x1,x2 etc) to access it:

```
let stringDictionary = ["a1": "This is some text", "a2": "This is more text"]
```

You can then pull it out using:

```
let x : Int = 1
let stringKey = "a\(x)"
let stringValue = stringDictionary[stringKey]
print(stringValue)
```

Comment: Thanks Joe! Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an eval or evaluate type function, but that doesn't exist. What you're actually getting is a description of the `x` variable, which is the number 1 converted into text, hence `a1`.

If you want to get a value for a key you should use a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the help! New to programming and wrapping my head around this stuff is very new to me.